# tkraise and some OOP issues in python GUI(tkinter)

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am a beginner at python with very minimal training on the basics of python and a bit of OOP basics. I was trying to make a GUI that can redirect to multiple pages and I made my GUI as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mx
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
  
# Initialize The Planar code Changing Functionality frame 
class PGcodefixer(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.config(width = 950, height = 587)
        self.controller = controller
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self.grid_propagate(False)
        self.errflag = 0
        
        # Initialize Labels
        self.img3 = Image.open(r"C:\some\path\here") 
        self.img32 = self.img3.resize((250,250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        self.img3final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img32)

        # Initialize styling of ttk widgets
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.theme_use("alt") 
        self.style.configure("Heading.TLabel", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "20", "bold"), justify = "center", compound  = "top", background = "#568BFC", foreground = "white")
        self.style.configure("TLabel", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "15", "bold"), justify = "center", compound  = "top", background = "#568BFC", foreground = "white") 
        self.style.configure("TButton", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "11", "bold"), justify = "center", Expand = True, background = "#FCC756", foreground = "white")
        self.style.configure("TEntry", justify = "center", Expand = True, background = "#FCC756", foreground = "Black")
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background = "#568BFC") # Background color in Hexcode

# Initialize The Nonplanar code Changing Functionality frame (Work in progress)
class NPGcodefixer(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,container, controller):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.controller = controller
        self.config(width = 950, height = 587)
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self.grid_propagate(False)

        # Initialize Labels
        self.img2 = Image.open(r"C:\some\path\here") 
        self.img22 = self.img2.resize((200,200), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        self.img2final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img22) 

        # Initialize the styling of ttk widgets
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.theme_use("alt") 
        self.style.configure("TLabel", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "16", "bold"), justify = "center", compound  = "top", background = "#DDE805", foreground = "white") 
        self.style.configure("TButton", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "11", "bold"), justify = "center", Expand = True, background = "#F57FF1", foreground = "white")
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background = "#DDE805") 

# Initialize The Homepage Frame
class Homepage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.controller = controller
        self.config(width = 950, height = 587)
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self.grid_propagate(False)
            
        # Initialize Labels (The first two lines correspond to how you are supposed to put an image into tkinter using Pillow)
        self.img1 = Image.open(r"C:\some\path\here")
        self.img12 = self.img1.resize((200,200), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) 
        self.img1final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img12) 
        self.labelh1 = ttk.Label(self, image = self.img1final, text = "Welcome to the Timesaver!\n Select the function you wish to use").place(relx = 0.315, rely = 0.15)
    
        # Initialize Button
        self.buttonh1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Planar Gcode Compiler", command = controller.showframe(self = App, frame = "PGcodefixer")).place(relx = 0.2255, rely = 0.65)
        self.buttonh2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Nonplanar Gcode Compiler", command = controller.showframe(self = App, frame = "NPGcodefixer")).place(relx = 0.55, rely = 0.65)
        self.buttonh3 = ttk.Button(self, text = "About", command = self.AboutMsg).place(relx = 0.85, rely = 0.9)

        # Initialize the styling of ttk Widgets
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.theme_use("alt") # To enable the button color to be changed, standard ttk will not allow it.
        self.style.configure("TLabel", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "16", "bold"), justify = "center", compound  = "top", background = "#FFB6C1", foreground = "white") # Compound method for relative positioning of text and Image
        self.style.configure("TButton", font = ("Comic Sans MS", "11", "bold"), justify = "center", Expand = True, background = "#67EB67", foreground = "white")
        self.style.configure("TFrame", background = "#FFB6C1") # Background color in Hexcode

    # Initialize a popup about Window for those interested to know more
    def AboutMsg(self):
        mx.showinfo(title = 'About', message =
                'Multi-Purpose Timesaver ver1.0\n'
                'Designed by X')   

# 5. Initialize App as a class
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initializing Window
        self.title("IMPT - Internship Multi-Purpose Timesaver") # Window Title
        self.geometry("950x587") # Using Golden Ratio, haha. Just the Window Size
        self.resizable(False, False) 
        H = Homepage(self, App).pack()
        P = PGcodefixer(self,App).pack()
        N = NPGcodefixer(self,App).pack()
        self.frames = {"Homepage": H, "PGCodefixer": P, "NPGcodefixer": N}

    def showframe(self, frame):
        if frame in self.frames.keys():
            print("yes")
            self.frames[frame].tkraise(self) #The self was asked for by vscode as positional argument is missing without it.
        else:
            print("no")
            pass

# 6. Bootstrapping the App
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    App.showframe("Homepage")
    app.mainloop()
```

I am confused about 3 main things, and would greatly appreciate your help with them.

1. How does super(init) container work? especially for the first frame initialized at the top - which class is container being inherited from?
2. Why is the controller and self not recognized in the code(i.e. controller.function is just not executed at all(checked with print statements)
3. related to 2. - I considered initializing a mixin class at the very top to store the tkraise method (among others in the future) and dictionary of frames, but found that to be rather weird(i.e. it would raise some frames(specifically their background colour and button colours), but not their buttons or other widgets which remained the same as that of the previous frame. Is this a possible solution to implement the frame tkraise method, and is my current solution(in terms of methodology) a good one?

   Once again, thank you for your help. A lot of solutions for the tkraise method online have used tk.frame but I haven't found one that uses ttk.frame and so I was quite lost. I am a beginner in terms of programming GUIs (and even to programming in general - I am trying to learn by trial and error) and this is my first major step on tkinter, and so even if you have any tips to provide in terms of structuring my code/bad programming practices(e.g. bad O(n) anywhere? etc.) to avoid that I am making, I would greatly appreciate them as well!

EDIT: Included a couple of missing lines of code showing the implementation of tkraise, and added assignment of controller to the controller class.

EDIT2: Added assignment of controller functions to self as they are methods.

EDIT3: I also realized upon further testing that str(classname) does not equal "classname" and so Ichanged the criteria. owever, upon calling the showframe method from the buttons, it is just not executed for some reason which really confused me.. why does this happen? I wanted to use the type change method (if str(x) in a list of strings to avoid making multiple duplicate instances of the class needlessly. I am now quite lost as to whether my approach is even the right one here to implement tkraise..Please help!!

EDIT4: Took into account Mr Roberts' suggestion to add the instances of frames into a list. But now an AttributeError pops up that self.frames is not an attribute of App, despite being a dictionary initialized within the instance of App in the first place. How do I proceed?

EDIT 5: Fixed the erroneous instance for tkraise as self.frames[frame].tkraise(self) and fixed another typo in import statement

Comment: Your `showframe` isn't going to work.  Remember that `Homepage` is not an object -- it is a CLASS.  Your `app.__init__` creates three instances -- one of each class.  When you get to `showframe`, the frame is going to be one of those objects.  It will not be a `Homepage` -- it will be an object of type `Homepage`.  You can save those three instances in variables or in a list, and compare against that list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried adding the instances into a dictionary with strings and attempted to proceed that way to avoid any potential recursion issues and wasteful duplicate instaces. However, I am now faced with an attribute error which does not seem to make sense, as I have already initialized an instance of app with the required attributes(self.frames) before proceeding with calling the showframe function. However, I ams facing Attribute error that self.frames the dictionary is not an attribute of App. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You have `App.showframe()`.  You need `app.showframe()`.  Do you see the differene?  Both calls are legal, but they mean very different things.

Comment: I have tried to use that as well, but the error remains the same. I do not see the main difference in both calls though - whether an instance or the class itself, both objects should have the same attributes and methods, right?

Comment: Using `.pack()` on those frames will show the frames together side by side vertically.  So calling `.tkraise()` on them is useless because they are all visible.  Note also that `command=controller.showframe(...)` will execute `controller.showframe(...)` *immediately* and assign the result (which is `None` for your case) to `command` option, therefore clicking the button later will do nothing.

Comment: Typo error `typeimport tkinter as tk` should be `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: Is that what is look like? https://ibb.co/PW4WXqz

Comment: acw 1668 and toyota Supra, thank you for your comments on this. I now seem to understand why the themes are mixed up - its because the frames are all visible together which is leading toa mishmash of colour and themes and widgets. Toyota supra, the picture is correct except the background shld be pink and the buttons shld be green. The theme of botton and background colour in your photo is actually that of PGcodefixer

Comment: That being said, how do I stack the frames vertically on top of one another? it it by assigning grid(0,0) to each frame? or are there other ways to do so which I am missing?

Comment: Both buttons doesn't work, except  about button. I got yellow background. Those image should be different?

Comment: I see, I was stuck at an attribute error and couldnt even run my code, how did you manage to overcome that? The attributeerror I got is in edit4

Comment: https://ibb.co/Yk8LsdW

Comment: I fixed the statement, my code is actually supposed to have self.frames[frame].tkraise(self) as frame instances are the values and the input strings are the keys in self.frames in App. I tried your code as well but I ran into the same error

Comment: Perhaps any future comment could be worded as a a separate answer to avoid oversaturating the comment section on the OP? Thank you!!

Comment: You can use chat discussion. I don't  know how to do.

Comment: @NVR-Youngboy -- there is a huge difference between a class and an instance of the class.  Consider the class `int`.  `a = 7` / `b = int` / `a += 1` / `b += 1`.  Very different meanings.  You create an instance, then you work with the instance.

Comment: @Tim Roberts -- I think I understand now - the instance has a value assigned to it that can be manipulated but the class itself does not and manipulating its(the class's) value would be meaningless. Did I understand it right?

Comment: For now, yes.  I'm being a little bit cagey, because a class CAN have its own members that are global to all instances, but that's a more advanced technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

```py
class Homepage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        ...
        # Initialize Button
        self.buttonh1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Planar Gcode Compiler", command = controller.showframe(self = App, frame = "PGcodefixer")).place(relx = 0.2255, rely = 0.65)
        self.buttonh2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Nonplanar Gcode Compiler", command = controller.showframe(self = App, frame = "NPGcodefixer")).place(relx = 0.55, rely = 0.65)
        self.buttonh3 = ttk.Button(self, text = "About", command = self.AboutMsg).place(relx = 0.85, rely = 0.9)
        ...
```

In the above code:

- `command = controller.showframe(...)` will execute `controller(...)` *immediately* and assign the result (which is `None`) to `command` option, so clicking the button later will do nothing.  Use `command = lambda: controller.showframe(...)` instead
- `controller.showframe(self = App, frame = "...")` should be `controller.showframe("...")` instead

---

```py
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        H = Homepage(self, App).pack()
        P = PGcodefixer(self,App).pack()
        N = NPGcodefixer(self,App).pack()
        self.frames = {"Homepage": H, "PGCodefixer": P, "NPGcodefixer": N}
   ...
```

- `H = Homepage(self, App).pack()` will assign the result of `.pack()` to `H`, so `H` will be `None`. Separate the line into two lines: `H = Homepage(...)` and `H.pack()` (actually using `.pack()` here is not the correct layout function for your case).  Same for `P` and `N` as well.
- Using `App` as the *controller* is wrong, use `self` instead

---

```py
    def showframe(self, frame):
        if frame in self.frames.keys():
            print("yes")
            self.frames[frame].tkraise(self) #The self was asked for by vscode as positional argument is missing without it.
        else:
            print("no")
            pass
```

In the above code, `self.frames[frame].tkraise(self)` should be `self.frames[frame].tkraise()` instead

---

So the updated code should be as below:

```py
class Homepage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        ...
        # Initialize Button
        ### use lambda in command option and pass the class name only to showframe()
        ttk.Button(self, text = "Planar Gcode Compiler", command = lambda: controller.showframe("PGcodefixer")).place(relx = 0.2255, rely = 0.65)
        ttk.Button(self, text = "Nonplanar Gcode Compiler", command = lambda: controller.showframe("NPGcodefixer")).place(relx = 0.55, rely = 0.65)
        ttk.Button(self, text = "About", command = self.AboutMsg).place(relx = 0.85, rely = 0.9)
        ...

    ...

# 5. Initialize App as a class
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

        # make the widget put at (0, 0) occupy all the available space
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        H = Homepage(self, self)  # use self as the controller argument
        P = PGcodefixer(self, self)
        N = NPGcodefixer(self, self)
        self.frames = {"Homepage": H, "PGcodefixer": P, "NPGcodefixer": N}

        # use grid() to overlay frames on top of each other
        H.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        P.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        N.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    def showframe(self, frame):
        if frame in self.frames:   # .keys() is not necessary
            print("yes")
            self.frames[frame].tkraise()  # removed self argument passed to tkraise()
        else:
            print("no")

# 6. Bootstrapping the App
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    # use the instance "app" instead of class name "App" to call .showframe(...)
    app.showframe("Homepage")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: line 2410, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  [Previous line repeated 792 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: It coming from line 93 and line 71.

Comment: @toyotaSupra The line numbers are meaningless as my sample code is a modified version of OP code.  Please post constructive comment instead.  Note that there is no such error in my sample code.

Comment: acw1668, Thank you so much for your help, I was finally able to make it work thanks to your suggestions!!! Do you mind explaining th reasoning behind why the controller should have been self and not app, and why you deicded to remove the self argument in tkraise? Also, why is it that when I use command = self.aboutmsg, aboutmsg does not get executed immediately but command = controller.shoeframe means that controller.shoeframe gets executed immediately? I would really appreciate your insights on this. Thank you so much once again for your solution!

Comment: 1) `self` is the instance of `App` and you need to pass the instance (i.e. `self`), not the `App` class; 2) ask yourself why do you need to pass `self` to `tkraise()`? 3) `self.aboutmsg` (without `()`) is the name of the function, but `controller.showFrame(...)` (with `(...)`) is not just the name of the function, it will execute the function.

Comment: Ahh I see, I understand it much better now! Thank you acw1668!!

Answer (score 0):

1. *How does `super(init)` work?*

Well, that's not what you have.  What you have is `super().__init__`.  Your first class (`PGcodefixer`) inherits from `ttk.Frame`, so `super().__init__` is the same as typing `ttk.Frame.__init__`.  If your class were to inherit from multiple parent classes, the `super()` processing is more complicated, but if you just derive from one base, the concept is pretty easy.

2. Why is the controller and self not recognized...

You have `controller` as a parameter to your constructors, but you're not saving that parameter anywhere.  If you need it later, you need to do something like `self.controller = controller` so you can refer to it later.

Remember that `self` is not magic in any way.  It's just a parameter name.  By convention, the first parameter in a class method is called `self`, but like all function parameters, that only lasts for the life of the function.  Unlike `this` is C++, you CAN use another name, but you would earn eternal scorn from the Python community.

3. Mixin for tkraise?

I don't see tkraise in this code, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Mixins can be a useful way to reduce repetitive typing, but only if the code is truly "universal".  If you're adding excepts and special cases, then maybe it isn't such a good idea.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply! Im really sorry I think I made an error as I forgot a couple of lines that had the tkraise function. Let me try your tip and I will paste the edited code onto the main question shortly!

Comment: I made the edits that you suggested and have tried to run my code! however, it now says that the showframe argument takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Should I add multiple inheritance directly with the App controller class to sort this issue? It seems that python does not recognize the initialization of the frame as requiring two arguments despite me specifying so in the init function.

Comment: `showframe` needs a `self`, because it is a method.  `def showframe(self, frame):`

Comment: Noted! I made the fix, and one of the issues I had earlier in testing cropped up - The frame that was raised had the buttons present of the correct frame, as well as the image, but the colour palette belonged to one of the frames below the frame that was supposed to be raised(Homepage). Furthermore, pressing the buttons which was supposed to raise the other frames did not even execute the showframe method as the word in the print statement did not even show despite the conditions being met!

Comment: I think there seems to be some fundamental aspect of inheritance that I seem to be missing here - the frame seemed to inherit some aesthetics but not others despite all being specified and self. -assigned(though I dont know if that is always necessary) OR is it that some aspect of the frames can be hidden while others"shine through" or something? I am still pretty lost about the big picture and I would be grateful if you could provide some pointers on the general workings of inheritance and assignment and frame mechanics. Thank you for taking your time to correspond with me!

Comment: A frame by itself doesn't have very many aesthetics.  It is just a container that holds other things.